# Power down USB subdevice (webcam)

Tags: usb, webcam, udev

In my laptop I have normal HD Camera and an IR Camera. I would like to power off the latter as it sometimes get auto-selected by some apps for video call. The issue is that the IR camera is a "subdevice" of the HD Camera so blacklisting it in udev won't really work here because I'd lose the HD camera too. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: So its a single camera with 2 features? If so do not see how you would do this.

Comment: You could try to implement a physical switch on the hardware.